# How do I get FlowPlayer 5.4.3 to start in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

How do I do this, I've been trying for about an hour and the video works, it just does not start in fullscreen mode!

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.3/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.3/skin/minimalist.css">

<script>

flowplayer.conf = {
   native_fullscreen: 'true',
   fullscreen: 'true',
   muted: 'true'
};

</script>
```

and the output html:

```
<div class="flowplayer" id="flowplayer" >

    <video autoplay>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="[[+FlowplayerVideo]]">
    </video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting these errors because the browser does not support it. If you look in [flowplayer docs](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html) under Methods There is a fullscreen() method. This states

> Note: Many browsers allow this method to work only from events which are triggered by user interaction, like "click", and not for example from player events like "ready" which happen at moments undetermined by the user.